# Unable to save the firebase activity state

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
The Main Dashboard File of the App
Dashboard.java
package com.abc.farmersconsult;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

 public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


  private EditText editText;
  private Spinner spinner;
  FirebaseAuth mAuth;
  DatabaseReference userRef;

  FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner_countries);
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
 android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
  CountryData.countrynames));

    editText = findViewById(R.id.Phone);


    findViewById(R.id.Continue).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
   {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String code = 
  CountryData.countryAreaCodes[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()];

            String number = editText.getText().toString().trim();

            if (number.isEmpty() || number.length() < 10) {
                editText.setError("Valid number is required");
                editText.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            String phoneNumber = "+" + code + number;

            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, 
            VerifyPhone.class);
            intent.putExtra("phonenumbers", phoneNumber);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
       });
      }


   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseUser currentUser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    UpdateUI(currentUser);
  /*
     if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        startActivity(intent);
    } */





   }

   private void UpdateUI(FirebaseUser currentUser) {
      if(currentUser!=null){
        Intent intent=new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, Dashboard.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| 
     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }




    }
   }
```

This File is The Profile Setup Activity

```
SetupProfile.java
public class SetupProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editText;
Button button;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
DatabaseReference mUserRef;
String CurrentUserID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup_profile);

    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    CurrentUserID=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mUserRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().
    child("Users").child(CurrentUserID);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveAccount();
        }
    });
}

private void saveAccount() {

String username=editText.getText().toString().trim();
if(username.isEmpty()){
    Toast.makeText(this,"Enter valid name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{
    HashMap userMap= new HashMap();
    userMap.put("username",username);
    mUserRef.updateChildren(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new 
    OnCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
         if(task.isSuccessful()){
             Toast.makeText(SetupProfile.this,"Account 
       create",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             sendHome();
         }
        }
    });
}

}

    private void sendHome() {
     Intent intent=new Intent(SetupProfile.this, Dashboard.class);



    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    }


     }



This File Contains Verification of the OTP file
VerifyPhone.java
public class VerifyPhone extends AppCompatActivity {

   private String verificationId;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    private EditText editText;
    DatabaseReference userRef;
   private ProgressBar progressBar;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_phone);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.verify_otp);

      String phonenumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("phonenumbers");
      sendVerificationCode(phonenumber);

       findViewById(R.id.Sign).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String code = editText.getText().toString().trim();

            if (code.isEmpty() || code.length() < 6) {

                editText.setError("Enter code...");
                editText.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            verifyCode(code);
        }
       });

      }













   private void verifyCode(String code) {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    signInWithCredential(credential);
   }

     private void checkExistence() {

    }

    private void SendUserToSetup() {
    Intent intent=new Intent(VerifyPhone.this, SetupProfile.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    }




       private void signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
       mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        final String current_userid=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        userRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                        userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(current_userid)){
                                    SendUserToSetup();
                                }



                                else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhone.this, Dashboard.class);
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });





                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(VerifyPhone.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();



}

private void sendVerificationCode(String number) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            number,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
            mCallBack
    );

}

private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
        mCallBack = new 
 PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken 
forceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
        verificationId = s;
    }

    @Override
     public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

        String code = credential.getSmsCode();
        if (code != null) {
            editText.setText(code);
            verifyCode(code);
        }
        signInWithCredential(credential);

    }


    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
        Toast.makeText(VerifyPhone.this, e.getMessage(), 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    };
   }
```

RegisterPhone.java

package com.abc.farmersconsult;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;


public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private EditText editText;
private Spinner spinner;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
DatabaseReference userRef;

FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner_countries);
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
    CountryData.countrynames));

    editText = findViewById(R.id.Phone);


    findViewById(R.id.Continue).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
   {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String code = 
     CountryData.countryAreaCodes[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()];

            String number = editText.getText().toString().trim();

            if (number.isEmpty() || number.length() < 10) {
                editText.setError("Valid number is required");
                editText.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            String phoneNumber = "+" + code + number;

            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, 
        VerifyPhone.class);
            intent.putExtra("phonenumbers", phoneNumber);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        });
      }


   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

      FirebaseUser currentUser=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
      UpdateUI(currentUser);
   /*
   if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        startActivity(intent);
     } */





}

  private void UpdateUI(FirebaseUser currentUser) {
    if(currentUser!=null){
        Intent intent=new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, Dashboard.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| 
  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }




}
}
```

There are Four Files Namely Dashboard.java, VerifyPhone.java, RegisterPhone.java and SetupProfile.java, I am able to perform OTP Authentication Successfully and Move to Setup Profile Activity and then the app moves to the Dashboard.java

The Problem is if  I exit the app it starts with Dashboard.java,it doesnot resume the profile setup activity.
It directly logs into the Dashboard everytime i perform sign in, I want the app to resume the incomplete account setup upon opening the application please help

Comment: I didn't see your `Dashboard.java`, `RegisterPhone.java`. And in your `RegisterActivity`, I didn't see anything that make your user go to `SetupProfileActivity`. I only see in your `UpdateUI()`, it always go to `Dashboard` when there's user in it.

Comment: Ive used Onstart method in registerActivity.java , I am unable to figure out how I could continue the incomplete setProfile activity after come back and exit the app

Comment: How to know whether a profile is complete or incomplete? Is it if they have verify their email? Or they have put their phone number? or etc?

Comment: The Problem is OTP authentication goes well , it directs the users to Profile Activity In my case Ive used just a  text field and a button to save even Profile Activity works well leading me to Home activity the real issue is with the profile activity whenever I exit the app the App takes me to Dashboard, I cant come back in case of incomplete exit

Answer (score 0):

After trying to understand your code (which you need to improve on how to write it in StackOverflow), I think the problem is because you just forget to sign-out when the app exit.

Firebase will keep your user signed-in, even after you exit your app. So that's why in your `RegisterActivity`, the result will always come true, as there is always a `FirebaseUser` in `FirebaseAuth`. Solution is: You have to make sure they signed-out when they re-enter the app.

**Suggestions**

You can signout every time your Activity is destroyed (or everytime user opens the app). Making sure they always start fresh.

Comment: Please Could you suggest come modifications in my register activity in the onstart activity

Comment: Try to call `FirebaseAuth.signOut()` in your `RegisterActivity.onCreate()`. And put your `onStart()` code in `onResume()`. It's much better that way.